# Webpack bundle node_modules to entry point specific files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I have an application, that has two entry points:

```
//entryA.js
import someModule from 'someModule'; // imports from node_module folder
import otherModule from 'otherModule'; // imports from node_module folder

...
```

```
//entryB.js
import someModule from 'someModule'; // imports from node_module folder

...
```

These are separate entries and separate js files should be created for them, in the lines of 'entryA.js' and 'entryB.js'.

What I would like to achieve, is to bundle the imported node_modules that these files use, to separate vendor js files, 'vendor.entryA.js' and 'vendor.entryB.js'.

`vendor.entryA.js` should contain the `someModule` and `otherModule` bundled, while `vendor.entryB.js` should contain only the `someModule` bundled.

I was experimenting with `splitChunks` options, and using this:

```
{
 splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: "vendor",
        chunks: 'all'
      }
    }
 }
}
```

managed to bundle all node_modules from these files, into a separate file, called `vendor.js`. But this way, if I have an entry file, that uses a single node_module, and another entry file, that uses 1000+, if a user wants to access only the smaller entry file, he will need to download 999 vendor files that are not needed by him.

How would I proceed to achieve the above scenario that I've mentioned?

Other things I've tried, which resulted seemingly in what I was expecting, is specifying cache groups the following way:

```
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    entryA: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name: "entryA.vendor",
      chunks: (chunk) => {
        return chunk.name === "entryA";
      }
    },
    entryB: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name: "entryB.vendor",
      chunks: (chunk) => {
        return chunk.name === "entryB";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in creating two vendor files, that seemingly contain the node_modules that I need, but I don't know if this is only eventual, or this is the way to do it.

Can someone either point me in the right direction, or try to give a small explanation on how the "chunks" work internally in webpack?